# error TS2307: Cannot find module (but it can when running the js)

Tags: typescript, requirejs, swagger-editor

Here is the scenario:

Using Swagger, I have created an api spec for my REST service. I then generate the angular typescript boilerplate files for calling into my service from the Swagger Editor tool.

When I generate the boilerplate files there are multiple files that all use typescript internal namespace while the rest of my project is AMD so I am trying to treat this compilation as if it is a third party non-AMD library. When I compile the typescript files I am emitting to a single javascript file.

My project uses RequireJS and I have registered my single javascript file with RequireJS like so:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: 'myApi': 'my/path/to/myApi', // There is no ts file with this name but there is a js once compiled
    shim: {
        'myApi': {
            init: () => {
                return this.API;  // The top level object from the boilerplate is API
            },
            exports: 'myApi'
        }
    }
}
```

})

In another file I have the code:

```
import myApi = require('myApi');
console.log(myApi);
```

In this same file I have above it:

```
import angular = require('angular');
```

which is registered with RequireJS in a similar way as myApi. Typescript doesn;t have a problem finding angular.

When I compile my project I get typescript

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'myApi' from the file trying to
>   import it.

When I run the actual project the correct myApi object gets logged to the console.

How can I make Typescript see this module (or otherwise suppress this error message)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm going with is to generate my files and then modify them manually to be external modules instead of internal. The alternative would be to modify the swagger codegen source to generate my files as external but for now the manual way will have to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? I'm having the same issue, yet I don't understand what you're doing.